# How do I create a scope for an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

The following code gives an empty scope. `Category_ids` is an array of categories.

```
scope :art, ->{ where(:category_ids => '1') }
```

How do I check to see if one of the categories exist in the array?

Comment: what database are you using ? Postgres/MySQL/ ... ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Postgres you can use this approach: https://www.viget.com/articles/searching-serialized-fields-in-rails-using-postgres-arrays

Answer (score 0):

1. get the categories
2. correct your where query

Example:

```
has_many :categories
scope :art, -> { required = [Category.first]; where(categories: required) }
```

I assume that in your model, you have `categories` association. In this case, you can just use `categories: required` in your where query. `required` should be set to an array of categories which you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You say that category_ids is an array of categories(I'm assuming category id's). Are you trying to return all records with a category ID that is in that array? If so you're looking for:

```
scope :art, -> { where (:category_id => category_ids) }
```

Or with the new ruby syntax:

```
scope :art, -> { where(category_id: category_ids) }
```

If I've misunderstood and you're looking for any record with a category ID of 1, then you're looking for:

```
scope :art, -> { where(category_id: '1') }
```